# Are Settings files available for web apps?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'd like to add a Settings.settings file to a web app in VS.NET 2010.  But I don't see this option.  Is not available for web apps?

Comment: Are you putting your application logic in a DLL that you wrote?  Put your settings there.

Comment: The values need to be accessed from the web app only.  Does that mean I need to use the web.config?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Comment: Just to confirm, no settings.settings for web apps?  Can you post as answer?

Comment: I could, but I'd just be duplicating the material at that MSDN article.  AFAIK settings.settings is reserved for your own DLL's and EXE's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its possible. Cant remember if I created folder "Properties" and file "Settings.settings" myself though.
[image]

Comment: I don't see it as an option for web app or website.

Comment: I think I ran into same issues. There were three options:  
1. Put all settings into web.config  
2. Create Settings.settings in a Properties folder  
3. Create an extra config.config or web.config (an option for this should be available in VS)

Comment: Where do you see those options?

Comment: I see only option 3 in VS interface. Do you have a "Properties" folder? If not, try to create one and a "Settings.settings" file manually.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing, but it isn't an option for web app or website.  It won't create the same type of properties folder.  It will be yellow.

Comment: Strange. I just created 2 new "ASP.NET Web Application" projects (.net 3.5 and 4.0) and they both have a "Properties" folder (without Settings.settings however, but this is no problem). 1. Which .net version you use? 2. Which project you chose? 3. Could you provide an image of your solution explorer please?